# Sabre API GET request failing due to invalid credentials

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sabre

I'm trying to use Postman to see my response and I'm getting an invalid credentials error message. I got a token from the headers using the base 64 code and my client credentials.

I used the access_token that I received to make a 'GET' request to:

```
https://api.havail.sabre.com/v2/shop/flights/fares?origin=CLT&departuredate=2015-12-15&returndate=2015-12-25&maxfare=220
```

Using Headers: `Authorization: Bearer <token>`, and `Content-Type: application/json`.

The response was this:

```
{
    "status": "NotProcessed",
    "type": "Validation",
    "errorCode": "ERR.2SG.SEC.INVALID_CREDENTIALS",
    "timeStamp": "2017-09-20T16:24:12.449-05:00",
    "message": "Authentication failed due to invalid credentials"
}
```

Is anyone having the same issue as me? Could anyone explain why please? The token has my credentials so I'm not sure why it's saying invalid credentials.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a TEST token, you should be using the TEST endpoint as well.

> https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/